thread pool start reject task ,how come active threads count is so so small?

I hava a ThreadPoolExecutor configed in prod, when the pool start to reject task ,the active threads is much smaller than core threads count 。
Thread pool config :
core threads:64
max threads:64
keep alive time:60s
queue : linked blocking queuq ,size 256
RejectedExecutionHandler:AbortPolicy

reject ThreadPoolExecutor snapshot is :
pool size :64
active threads:1
queued tasks : 256

I think most threads should be active ,when the pool starts to reject task. but active threads is much small then expected.
